# jquery variable scope

Tags: jquery, variables, scope

I have this code in jquery:

```
var ratio;
$("<img/>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function() {
ratio = this.width / this.height;
    alert(ratio);
});
```

This retuns the correct ratio, but when I try this

```
var ratio;
$("<img/>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function() {
ratio = this.width / this.height;        
});
alert(ratio);
```

It returns *undefined*.

I do not understand why this happens even though I have declared globally the ratio variable.

I use this in the following exemple:

**working** http://jsfiddle.net/7sUAY/5/

**not working** http://jsfiddle.net/7sUAY/6/

Thank you,
Mugur

Comment: Because the `load` callback is executed only when the image was loaded, whereas every code following `$("<img/>").attr().load()` is executed immediately. Otherwise, what would be the reason to provide a callback at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only assign a value to `ratio` inside a callback (passed to the load function). This callback will be made when the image has loaded. It will not have been made before the point where `ratio` is alerted and so `ratio` remains undefined.

See [here for the load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `.load()` method takes more time. Your alert is executed faster than the image has been loaded.